# Html.Serialize error in modelState

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

Im trying to make a Wizard registration form (multistep registration) in asp.net mvc.

I have a Login page (with an initial field: Name) . When I post, it goes to a register page and serialize the name field (that belongs to an ViewModel Step1 Object)

Everything seems to be working fine. I deserialize the object normally.

The problem is in ModelState. Its invalid every time because the hidden field serialized.

It shows me the exception for the hidden field: "The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Project.ViewModels.Step1' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."

What Im doing wrong? 
Why ModelState is trying to validate my hidden field????

My models:

```
public class Wizard
{
    public Step1 Step1 { get; set; }
    public Step2 Step2 { get; set; }
}

public class Step1
{
    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Step2
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

My method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register (Wizard user, FormCollection form, [Deserialize] Step1 step1)
    {
        if (form["Step2Button"] != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) //Is invalid every time
            {
                user.Step1 = step1;
                return View("RegisterFinal", user);
            }

            return View("Register", user);
        }
}
```

My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Serialize("Step1", Model.Step1)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Step2.Email)
    <button name="Step2Button">Continue</button>
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just used ModelState.Remove in the hidden field before validation.